# SQL query to get the correct fields

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a table below.

```
#  Company      CardType      ErrorCode
------------------------------------------
1  JPMorgan     Visa          01
2  JPMorgan     NULL          01
3  BoA          Visa          01
4  BoA          Visa          02
5  Citigroup    MasterCard    01
```

We have three fields, and CardType field is nullable.
What I want to do is find the correct match.
For example, if I pass into the query:

```
(JPMorgan, Visa, 01) it should match record 1.
```

But instead of Visa I pass in anything else for JPMorgan under CardType it should match the generic record with card type NULL. Like below.

```
(JPMorgan, MasterCard, 01) it should match record 2.
(JPMorgan, Chase, 01) it should match record 2.
(JPMorgan, NULL, 01) it should match record 2.
```

How do I go about achieving this?

```
DECLARE
@Company nvarchar(50)
@CardType nvarchar(50) = NULL
@ErrorCode nvarchar(50)

SET
@Company = 'JPMorgan'
@CardType = NULL
@ErrorCode = '01'

SELECT * FROM Bank
WHERE Company = @Company
AND (@CardType IS NULL OR CardType = @CardType)
AND ErrorCode = @ErrorCode
```

This is what I got however, this is not correct because when I pass in (JPMorgan, NULL, 01) it returns the wrong result.
Can someone please help me with this. I was told I have to use PARTITION and GROUP BY OR ROW_NUMBER to get this working but im not too sure.

Comment: why do you set @CardType = NULL if you already have a condition: AND (@CardType IS NULL OR CardType = @CardType)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the *best* match.  For that, `row_number()` is really a viable solution:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM (SELECT b.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ((CASE WHEN Company = @Company THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
                                          (CASE WHEN CardType = @CardType OR CardType IS NULL and @CardType IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
                                          (CASE WHEN ErrorCode = @ErrorCode THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                                         ) DESC
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM Bank b
      WHERE (Company = @Company OR @Company IS NULL) AND
            (CardType = @CardType OR
             @CardType IS NULL OR
             CardType IS NULL
            ) AND
            (ErrorCode = @ErrorCode OR @ErrorCode IS NULL)
     ) b
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```